# AutoReplace não funciona usando bootstrap fileinput

Tags: javascript, html5

A ideia é o seguinte:

Quando selecionar imagem, vai diretamente salvar no banco de dados sem usar botão salvar.

Aqui está um exemplo: http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input-ajax-demo/6

Segue o código:

**Html**:

```
<input id="input-705" name="kartik-input-705[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading">
```

**Script**:

```
<script>
var $input = $("#input-705");
$input.fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "@Url.Action("Upload", "Controller", new { id = Model.Id})", // server upload action
    uploadAsync: false,
    showUpload: false, // hide upload button
    showRemove: false, // hide remove button
    minFileCount: 1,
    maxFileCount: 1,
    autoReplace: true
}).on("filebatchselected", function(event, files) {
    // trigger upload method immediately after files are selected
    $input.fileinput("upload");
});
</script>
```

Na linha `autoReplace: true` não está funcionando.
Quando selecionar outra imagem, não está fazendo autoReplace.

No site dele fala o exemplo de autoReplace: http://plugins.krajee.com/file-auto-replace-demo

O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Comment: Um erro de sintaxe é a vírgula depois do `true`, comece por remove-la.

Comment: Já removi a vírgula, mesma assim continua

Comment: Segue a imagem, https://s27.postimg.org/j3q56mnlf/16_Jan_11_17_52.jpg